# Entity Framework Code First Many to Many Mapping is Being Ignored and also not saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I'm currently working on an application that works with dynamic questionnaire forms.
forms that are defined in a database like so: Forms > Sections > Controls > Questions.

Each Question can have many business rules such as: required, minlength, maxlength etc etc.

Each BusinessRule is the rule for exactly one Question. However, there are complex business rules that require fetching the value of another question. Therefore each Business Rule can have many Linked Questions to fetch a required value from.

I'm using code first for the first time and have the following defining classes and mapping for this relationship:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ValueTypeId { get; set; }
    public int ParentQuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ValueType ValueType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> ChildQuestions { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BusinessRule> BusinessRules { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BusinessRule> LinkedBusinessRules { get; set; }
}

public class BusinessRule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ValidationMessage { get; set; }
    public string ConditionValue { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int BusinessRuleTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual BusinessRuleType BusinessRuleType { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> LinkedQuestions { get; set; }
}

internal class QuestionConfigruation : EntityTypeConfiguration<Question>
{
    public QuestionConfigruation()
    {
        this.HasMany<Question>(q => q.ChildQuestions)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(q => q.ParentQuestionId);

        this.HasMany(q => q.BusinessRules)
            .WithRequired(br => br.Question)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

internal class BusinessRuleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<BusinessRule>
{
    public BusinessRuleConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(b => b.LinkedQuestions)
            .WithMany(q => q.LinkedBusinessRules)
            .Map(map =>
                {
                    map.ToTable("BusinessRuleLinkedQuestions");
                    map.MapLeftKey("LinkedQuestionId");
                    map.MapRightKey("BusinessRuleId");
                });
    }
}
```

This results in the following being produced in the database:

[image]

Finally, my questions:

**[Resolved]**

Why is the many to many join table ignoring the mappings for the table name and keys i've       specified in the BusinessRuleConfiguration?

**[/Resolved]**

When I try to insert a test form using a custom initialiser by doing this:

```
var companyName = new Question
        {
            Name = "CompanyName",
            ValueTypeId = _typeRepository.GetValueType(ValueTypes.String).Id,
            BusinessRules = new List<BusinessRule>{
                new BusinessRule
                {
                    BusinessRuleTypeId = _typeRepository.GetBusinessRuleType(BusinessRuleTypes.required).Id,
                    ValidationMessage = "Company name is required.",
                }
            }
        };


var form = new Form
{       
   Sections = new List<Section>
   {            
        new Section(){
            Controls = new List<Control>
            {
                new Control{
                     ControlTypeId = _typeRepository.GetControlType(ControlTypes.Textbox).Id

                     Questions = new List<Question>
                     {
                         companyName,
                     }
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

I get the following error:

`Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.`

I've spent far too long on this now trying resolve it, so help from someone with more experience with EF and Code First would be greatly appreciated. I'm starting to regret the choice of code first, but i don't know if it is code first thats the problem or my understanding of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the `BusinessRuleConfiguration` to the modelBuilder configurations in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: Yeah, same I am thinking. Have you added the configurations to the context class by overriding OnModelCreating()?  `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BusinessRuleConfiguration());`    `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new QuestionConfigruation());`

Comment: Ahhh, silly me i forgot to add the BusinessRule configuration. Thanks guys thats one issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

before we get into the entity framework things I believe that your models does not reflect your business problem correctly, and as a result the invalid relationships are causing the errors.

Can you please provide more information regarding the business problem around LinkedBusinessRules
BusinessRules

Based on what you have mentioned I see your question/businessrule classes looking more like this.

Things to note, 
Instead of having 'one question has on to many business rule AND that business rule has many questions'

Its now 'one question Has one to many business rules'.

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ValueTypeId { get; set; }
    public int ParentQuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual ValueType ValueType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BusinessRule> BusinessRules { get; set; }
}

public class BusinessRule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ValidationMessage { get; set; }
    public string ConditionValue { get; set; }
    public int BusinessRuleTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string BusinessRuleType { get; set; }
}
```

If you still have problems and have good db design skills, use a tool such as http://salardbcodegenerator.codeplex.com/
Then you can create your db first and generate classes based on that.

Comment: The relationship you've defined is fine if the business rules did not require another questions value.

Simple business rule: 

RuleType = maxlength, ConditionValue = 10;<br/><br/> 

But i have some rules that require values from other question like:

RuleType = SUM, QuestionIdsToSum = 1, 2, 3

I hope this helps clear up what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

First issue was because I had forgotten to add the BusinessRule configuration as point out by @Slauma and @Abhijit.

The second problem of saving a new form was actually to do with a number of problems that i didnt detail in the question.